# Parallelization inside a function in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, simulation

I apologize if that is a trivial question, but I am a newbie.

I need to simulate iid random variables inside a for loop (that I can not get rid of), and I want to do that using parallelization. I am using R.

If I parallelize the simulations *outside* the loop everything works fine. But as soon as I try to run this loop, the code is much slower of the non-parallelized version.

This is some reproducible code that shows the problem.

```
require(parallel)

N_iter = 1000
N = 100
begin_normalprocedure = Sys.time()
for (i in 1:N_iter){
  for (j in 1:N){
    rnorm(4)
  }  
}
end_normalprocedure = Sys.time()

print(paste("Time taken for normal procedure: ", end_normalprocedure  - begin_normalprocedure))


begin_parallelprocedure = Sys.time()
xlist <- sapply(1:N, list)
for (i in 1:N_iter){  
  
  ncores <- detectCores(logical=F)
  clust <- makeCluster(ncores)  
  parLapply(clust, xlist, function(x) {rnorm(4)})
  stopCluster(clust)
  
}
end_parallelprocedure = Sys.time()

print(paste("Time taken for parallelized procedure: ", end_parallelprocedure  - begin_parallelprocedure))
```

Is there an obvious reason for which this happens? Can I solve it somehow?

Thanks.

[If matters, I am using Windows]

Edit: I added reproducible code

Answer (score 0):

Cluster setup & cleanup only needs to happen once, not per loop iteration. You mentioned you also tried something like below. With the *parallel* code in your question, you perform the setup + cleanup overhead `N_iter` times.

```
library(parallel)
N_iter <- 1000
N <- 100
begin_parallelprocedure <- Sys.time()
xlist <- sapply(1:N, list)
ncores <- detectCores(logical=F)
clust <- makeCluster(ncores)
for (i in 1:N_iter){  
  parLapply(clust, xlist, function(x) {rnorm(4)})
}
stopCluster(clust)
end_parallelprocedure = Sys.time()

print(paste("Time taken for parallelized procedure: ", end_parallelprocedure  - begin_parallelprocedure))
#> [1] "Time taken for parallelized procedure:  1.52333998680115"
```

In my machine your non-parallel code took < 0.3 second and the parallel code above took ~1.5 seconds. So the overhead is about ~1.2 seconds per setup + cleanup. Multiply that by `N_iter == 1000` then that's about 1200 seconds = 20 minutes.

---

For your follow-up question I assume you are referring to your demo function which just calls `rnorm(4)`. This is too simple to make the overhead cost worth it. Try the example below instead.

```
cpu_intensive_calc <- function(x) { 
  Sys.sleep(3);     # calc takes 3 seconds...
  x * sum(rnorm(4)) # dummy calc that uses input param x
}

# reduce iterations so demo finishes in < 3 mins
N_iter <- 5
N <- 10

# sequential - this should take 5 * 10 * 3 secs = 150 secs = 02:30 mins
begin_normalprocedure <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:N_iter){
  for (j in 1:N){
    cpu_intensive_calc(j)
  }  
}
end_normalprocedure <- Sys.time()
print(end_normalprocedure - begin_normalprocedure)
#> Time difference of 2.500579 mins

# parallel
library(parallel)
begin_parallelprocedure <- Sys.time()
xlist <- sapply(1:N, list)
ncores <- detectCores(logical=F)  # I have 4 cores
clust <- makeCluster(ncores)
for (i in 1:N_iter){  
  parLapply(clust, xlist, cpu_intensive_calc)
}
stopCluster(clust)
end_parallelprocedure <- Sys.time()
print(end_parallelprocedure - begin_parallelprocedure)
#> Time difference of 45.6435 secs
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried that, but the problem persisted: in particular, the parallelization does not seem to have any effect at all on the speed of the code (in fact, it seems to slow things down - the time of the parallelized version is consistently higher than the other one).